# OptaPlanner - what is difference between xml files in "import" and "unsolved" folders? nurse roster example

Tags: drools, optaplanner

In the optaplanner data files for the nurse rostering example, I see xml data files inside two folders "import" and "unsolved" which have similar names except the ones inside the "unsolved" folder have reference tags for many of the xml tags.  For example, here is what long01.xml inside the "import" folder looks like:

```
<ShiftTypes>
    <Shift ID="E">
      <StartTime>06:30:00</StartTime>
      <EndTime>14:30:00</EndTime>
      <Description>Early shift type</Description>
      <Skills>
        <Skill>Nurse</Skill>
      </Skills>
    </Shift>
    <Shift ID="L">
      <StartTime>14:30:00</StartTime>
      <EndTime>22:30:00</EndTime>
      <Description>Late shift type</Description>
      <Skills>
        <Skill>Nurse</Skill>
      </Skills>
    </Shift>
    <Shift ID="D">
      <StartTime>08:30:00</StartTime>
      <EndTime>16:30:00</EndTime>
      <Description>Day shift type</Description>
      <Skills>
        <Skill>Nurse</Skill>
      </Skills>
    </Shift>
    <Shift ID="N">
      <StartTime>22:30:00</StartTime>
      <EndTime>06:30:00</EndTime>
      <Description>Night shift</Description>
      <Skills>
        <Skill>Nurse</Skill>
      </Skills>
    </Shift>
    <Shift ID="DH">
      <StartTime>08:30:00</StartTime>
      <EndTime>16:30:00</EndTime>
      <Description>Head nurse day shift type</Description>
      <Skills>
        <Skill>HeadNurse</Skill>
      </Skills>
    </Shift>
  </ShiftTypes>
```

But here is what the xml file with the same name inside the "unsolved" folder looks like:

```
  <firstShiftDate id="3">
  <id>0</id>
  <dayIndex>0</dayIndex>
  <date>2010-01-01</date>
  <shiftList id="4">
    <Shift id="5">
      <id>0</id>
      <shiftDate reference="3"/>
      <shiftType id="6">
        <id>0</id>
        <code>E</code>
        <index>0</index>
        <startTimeString>06:30:00</startTimeString>
        <endTimeString>14:30:00</endTimeString>
        <night>false</night>
        <description>Early shift type</description>
        <shiftLength>2</shiftLength>
      </shiftType>
      <index>0</index>
      <requiredEmployeeSize>8</requiredEmployeeSize>
    </Shift>
    <Shift id="7">
      <id>1</id>
      <shiftDate reference="3"/>
      <shiftType id="8">
        <id>1</id>
        <code>L</code>
        <index>1</index>
        <startTimeString>14:30:00</startTimeString>
        <endTimeString>22:30:00</endTimeString>
        <night>false</night>
        <description>Late shift type</description>
        <shiftLength>2</shiftLength>
      </shiftType>
      <index>1</index>
      <requiredEmployeeSize>8</requiredEmployeeSize>
    </Shift>
    <Shift id="9">
      <id>2</id>
      <shiftDate reference="3"/>
      <shiftType id="10">
        <id>2</id>
        <code>D</code>
        <index>2</index>
        <startTimeString>08:30:00</startTimeString>
        <endTimeString>16:30:00</endTimeString>
        <night>false</night>
        <description>Day shift type</description>
        <shiftLength>2</shiftLength>
      </shiftType>
      <index>2</index>
      <requiredEmployeeSize>5</requiredEmployeeSize>
    </Shift>
    <Shift id="11">
      <id>3</id>
      <shiftDate reference="3"/>
      <shiftType id="12">
        <id>3</id>
        <code>N</code>
        <index>3</index>
        <startTimeString>22:30:00</startTimeString>
        <endTimeString>06:30:00</endTimeString>
        <night>true</night>
        <description>Night shift</description>
        <shiftLength>2</shiftLength>
      </shiftType>
      <index>3</index>
      <requiredEmployeeSize>6</requiredEmployeeSize>
    </Shift>
    <Shift id="13">
      <id>4</id>
      <shiftDate reference="3"/>
      <shiftType id="14">
        <id>4</id>
        <code>DH</code>
        <index>4</index>
        <startTimeString>08:30:00</startTimeString>
        <endTimeString>16:30:00</endTimeString>
        <night>false</night>
        <description>Head nurse day shift type</description>
        <shiftLength>2</shiftLength>
      </shiftType>
      <index>4</index>
      <requiredEmployeeSize>2</requiredEmployeeSize>
    </Shift>
  </shiftList>
</firstShiftDate>
<lastShiftDate id="15">
          <id>27</id>
          <dayIndex>27</dayIndex>
          <date>2010-01-28</date>
          <shiftList id="16">
            <Shift id="17">
              <id>135</id>
              <shiftDate reference="15"/>
              <shiftType reference="6"/>
              <index>135</index>
              <requiredEmployeeSize>8</requiredEmployeeSize>
            </Shift>
            <Shift id="18">
              <id>136</id>
              <shiftDate reference="15"/>
              <shiftType reference="8"/>
              <index>136</index>
              <requiredEmployeeSize>8</requiredEmployeeSize>
            </Shift>
            <Shift id="19">
              <id>137</id>
              <shiftDate reference="15"/>
              <shiftType reference="10"/>
              <index>137</index>
              <requiredEmployeeSize>5</requiredEmployeeSize>
            </Shift>
            <Shift id="20">
              <id>138</id>
              <shiftDate reference="15"/>
              <shiftType reference="12"/>
              <index>138</index>
              <requiredEmployeeSize>6</requiredEmployeeSize>
            </Shift>
            <Shift id="21">
              <id>139</id>
              <shiftDate reference="15"/>
              <shiftType reference="14"/>
              <index>139</index>
              <requiredEmployeeSize>2</requiredEmployeeSize>
            </Shift>
          </shiftList>
        </lastShiftDate>
        <planningWindowStart reference="3"/>
```

When you run the optaplanner example, it appears to allow you to select from a list of files which are from the "unsolved" folder.  Are the xml data files from "import" folder the "raw" xml files?

If I click on "Import" button and choose an xml file, then I assume it then opens the file and the creates an "unsolved" version of it?  Does this occur in the NurseRosterExporter.java?  If so, why do we need to do this and where is the exact code that adds the "reference" tags and creates all the new reference tags?

Why does there seem to be two steps to create the xml file -- you have the raw xml file then you need to import it, save it, then load it into the example -- is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The unsolved folder is using the XStream XML format of the Java domain objects.

The import folder is using the XML format as definied by the International Nurse Rostering Competition.

Regardless of which folder you read from, it's creates domain object in Java and that is what OptaPlanner works on. The XML read/writes are just there to facilitate the examples. Others use JSON, Excel files, ... [Optaweb-employee-rostering](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering) uses a database with a pretty web ui.

Comment: Do you know where is the specific code that handles importing the XStream XML files from the unsolved folder?  I'm trying to figure out how the initialized ShiftAssignments inside of the example "medium_late01_initialized_xml" are imported.  Is it nurserosteringapp.java?  Specifically this line:  " public SolutionFileIO<NurseRoster> createSolutionFileIO() {
        return new XStreamSolutionFileIO<>(NurseRoster.class);
    }"    This is all I could find....and I don't understand how it reads the XML tags for the ShiftAssignments which are not parsed by NurseRosteringImporter.java.  Thanks!